# validation image not detect

Tags: php, mysql, user-input

I have  Code to Create/Update/Delete my data from database.

I have data and a banner image. I do not want to update the image if only the data is set.

So, I try to make a code validator: if I update only data -not the image- my image is not set to null.

But my validation does not detect if I have filled my input file or not...

This my code:

```
<?php
 include ("config.php");
 $id= $_POST['id'];
 $konten3 = $_POST['konten3'];
 $footer=$_POST['footer'];
 $lokasi_file   = $_FILES['banner']['tmp_name'];
 $nama_file     = $_FILES['banner']['name'];

 if(isset($_FILES['banner'])) {
 $hapus = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM newsletter WHERE id='$id'");
 $r=mysql_fetch_array($hapus);
 $d = 'upload/'.$r['banner'];
 unlink ($d);
 move_uploaded_file($lokasi_file,"upload/".$nama_file);


 }if (empty($lokasi_file)) {
 if ($edit = mysql_query("UPDATE newsletter SET konten3='$konten3', footer='$footer' WHERE id='$id'")){
    header("Location: newsletter.php");
    exit();
}
die ("Terdapat kesalahan : ". mysqli_error($konek));

}
if ($edit = mysql_query("UPDATE newsletter SET banner='$nama_file', konten3='$konten3',footer='$footer' WHERE id='$id'")){
    header("Location: newsletter.php");
    exit();
}
die ("Terdapat kesalahan : ". mysql_error($konek));
?>
```

I am so happy if anyone can help me. i am try to update image with name banner

Comment: SQL Injection warning, nothing to do with your problem, but yet, please use bind parmaters

Comment: It's annoying seeing `mysql_*` functions still being used.

Comment: lol i am still use mysql T__T

Comment: @Gar ,use bind parameters? , ok i will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is in your conditions and in last query. i think in last update you dont need to update image. change your code as below

```
<?php
 include ("config.php");
 $id= $_POST['id'];
 $konten3 = $_POST['konten3'];
 $footer=$_POST['footer'];
 $lokasi_file   = $_FILES['banner']['tmp_name'];
 $nama_file     = $_FILES['banner']['name'];

 if(isset($_FILES['banner']) && $_FILES['banner']['name'] != "") {
 $hapus = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM newsletter WHERE id='$id'");
 $r=mysql_fetch_array($hapus);
 $d = 'upload/'.$r['banner'];
 unlink ($d);
 move_uploaded_file($lokasi_file,"upload/".$nama_file);


 }
if (!empty($lokasi_file)) { //change here need to check "not empty" instead of "empty"
 if ($edit = mysql_query("UPDATE newsletter SET banner='$nama_file',konten3='$konten3', footer='$footer' WHERE id='$id'")){
    header("Location: newsletter.php");
    exit();
}
die ("Terdapat kesalahan : ". mysqli_error($konek));

}
//Remove banner from below query
if ($edit = mysql_query("UPDATE newsletter SET , konten3='$konten3',footer='$footer' WHERE id='$id'")){
    header("Location: newsletter.php");
    exit();
}
die ("Terdapat kesalahan : ". mysql_error($konek));
?>
```

**EDIT**

Change your logic as below if banner is uploaded then move and update banner otherwise only update other data

```
<?php
 include ("config.php");
 $id= $_POST['id'];
 $konten3 = $_POST['konten3'];
 $footer=$_POST['footer'];
 $lokasi_file   = $_FILES['banner']['tmp_name'];
 $nama_file     = $_FILES['banner']['name'];

 if(isset($_FILES['banner']) && $_FILES['banner']['name'] != "") {
 $hapus = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM newsletter WHERE id='$id'");
 $r=mysql_fetch_array($hapus);
 $d = 'upload/'.$r['banner'];
 unlink ($d);
 move_uploaded_file($lokasi_file,"upload/".$nama_file);

 if ($edit = mysql_query("UPDATE newsletter SET banner='$nama_file',konten3='$konten3', footer='$footer' WHERE id='$id'")){
    header("Location: newsletter.php");
    exit();
}
 die ("Terdapat kesalahan : ". mysqli_error($konek));

 }

//Remove banner from below query
if ($edit = mysql_query("UPDATE newsletter SET , konten3='$konten3',footer='$footer' WHERE id='$id'")){
    header("Location: newsletter.php");
    exit();
}
die ("Terdapat kesalahan : ". mysql_error($konek));
?>
```

Comment: i am so happy with your help , but if try not to fill my banner at update my data , my banner still replace with blank data / null (cz file input can't put value from database)